# How to increment a variable within a loop to move an object a certain amount of points the rotate to a new direction

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

rotate in a clockwise square: first go North 3 times, then East 3 times, then South 3 times, then West 3 times then repeats.

Currently my code rotates the bird north to east to west, then north to east to south, and moves up 2 North, but doesn't increment any other direction

creating for loops with an array and a temp variable storing a string direction simply to check which direction is needed

```
public Direction getMove(){
        if(count > 12){
            count = 0;
        }else if(count <= 12){
            if(count >= 0 && count <= 3){
                count++;
                return Direction.NORTH;
            }else if(count > 3 && count <= 6){
                count++;
                return Direction.EAST;
            }else if(count > 6 && count <= 9){
                count++;
                return Direction.SOUTH;
            }else if(count > 9 && count <= 12){
                count++;
                return Direction.WEST;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code won't compile as given; if count is greater than 12, the method won't execute a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not compile due to missing return statement.

Here is a much simpler method , don't bother resting count just find it's modulus.

```
public Direction getMove()
{
   Object dir = Direction.WEST;    
   switch(count%4)
   {
      case 0: Direction.NORTH;
      case 1: Direction.NORTH;
      case 2: Direction.NORTH;    
   }
   count++;
   return dir;

 }
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I forgot to paste my return statement in, I fixed my error but thank you so much for helping :)